# NSolve question

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

I thought I could do this:
Define a list for variable `s`:

```
s = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}
```

Define a value for variable a:

```
a=45
```

Define a function:

```
q = r^4 - 4 r^3 - s^2 r^2 (1 - 3 (Sin[a π/180])^2) + 
  s^4 (Sin[a π/180])^2 + 4 s r Cos[a π/180] Sqrt[r (r^2 - s^2 (Sin[a π/180])^2)]
```

(This gives 10 functions of r only.)
Then do:

```
NSolve[q == 0, r, Reals]
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Look, `q` is a 10-vector depending on `r`. That can never equal a scala `0`. But I guess you'd like to solve each equation seperately. To this end, you can use, e.g.,  `Table[NSolve[eq == 0., r, Reals], {eq, q}]` instead. Btw.: I am pleased to see your kernel running again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
s = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9};
a = 45;
q = r^4 - 4 r^3 - s^2 r^2 (1-3 (Sin[a \[Pi]/180])^2) + s^4 (Sin[a \[Pi]/180])^2 + 
    4 s r Cos[a \[Pi]/180] Sqrt[r (r^2 - s^2 (Sin[a \[Pi]/180])^2)];
Table[NSolve[q[[i]] == 0, r, Reals], {i, Length[q]}]
```

This returns 10 r values, one for each equation. Or if you prefer not to use Table, you can use Map for the last line:

```
NSolve[q[[#]] == 0, r, Reals] & /@ Range[Length[q]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9} // Rationalize;

a = 45;

q = r^4 - 4 r^3 - s^2 r^2 (1 - 3 (Sin[a π/180])^2) + 
   s^4 (Sin[a π/180])^2 + 
   4 s r Cos[a π/180] Sqrt[r (r^2 - s^2 (Sin[a π/180])^2)];

(sol = (Solve[# == 0, r, Reals] & /@ q) /. x_Root :> N[x]) // Column
```

[image]